Why are Sephardic siddurim shorter than Ashkenaz ones?
I can only testify about the communities that I’ve been to but everywhere I go, the standard Ashkenaz siddur tends to be much taller and more rectangular than its Sephardic counterpart, which is usually shorter and almost square-like. Is there any halachic idea behind this difference?

Ashkenazim used to say more piyutim, but those aren't in most siddurim anymore

@Heshy I think the OP means the physical dimensions of the books, not the content.

Many Sephardi publishers have a smaller-format Mincha and Arvit only edition, which if you're not davenint Shacharit with a Sephardi minyan you're likely to see

Can you chalk it up to convenience? Its easier to carry around

I've noticed the same. I don't think there's a reason, besides maybe some historical reason based on custom or differences in printing in various regions. Or maybe their bookcases used to be different sizes. Artscroll makes all their siddurim the same.
